# how to use formarray of formgroups for mat-select in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I am working on a piece where I need a material select box which can have multiple values selected. The values in select box are coming from an API which has array of objects. My requirement is to create a formarray of formgroups when user selects any value in select box.

For eg:

Select box has category list. The category list is basically a list of category object. When I select any category value, I want the form to create a formarray of category objects.

**.html:**

```
<div formArrayName="category">
  <div *ngFor="let x of myForm.get('category')['controls'];let i = index">
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Category</mat-label>
        <mat-select [formControlName]="name" multiple>
          <mat-option [value]="category.name"
          *ngFor="let category of categories">
          {{category.name}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
        <!--
          <mat-error *ngIf="myForm.controls.category.touched && myForm.controls.category.invalid">
                  <span *ngIf="myForm.controls.category.errors.required">Please select category</span>
          </mat-error>-->
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**.ts :**

```
  category:this.fb.array([this.fb.group({
        "name":['']
      })]),
```

when i select any value i am getting the output like this

```
category: Array(1)
   0:
     name: Array(2)
        0: "Finance & Economics"
        1: "Data Science"
```

I want output like this:

```
category: Array(1)
   0:
     name: Array(2)
        0: "Finance & Economics"
   1:
     name: Array(2)
        0: "Data Science"
```

Can someone please help me to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

is

```
<div *ngFor="let x of myForm.get('category').controls;let i = index">
```

Better is use a getter, else Angular give you an error in production

```
get categoriesArray()
{
    return this.myForm.get('category') as FormArray
}
//And use

<div *ngFor="let x of categoriesArray.controls;let i = index">
```

And formControlName is without `[` `]`

```
<mat-select formControlName="name" multiple>
```